# Why do these programs performing the same calculation in a different order give me different output?

Tags: c++

Why is the output of these two programs different?  I have included the code so you can easily view it and try it.  Can anyone explain it to me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float pi = 3.14159;
    int r;

    while (cin >> r) {
        cout << "VOLUME = " << fixed << setprecision(3)
             << pi*r*r*r*(4.0/3.0) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float pi = 3.14159;
    int r;

    while (cin >> r) {
        cout << "VOLUME = " << fixed << setprecision(3)
             << (4.0/3.0)*r*r*r*pi << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I input 1523 the first one gives me 14797487059.353, which is the right answer, but the second one gives a negative number.

[The 2 screens with the outputs this link include the 2 outputs the first one ir the right the second one is weird !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46kUQ.jpg)

Comment: The problem is likely floating point imprecision.  Unless he didn't set the variables, then anything can happen. Can you post the complete program?

Comment: @spartygw [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262446/are-we-being-elitist-is-there-something-wrong-with-that/262455#262455). If you're willing to help him, spend the time and bang the question in proper shape by editing. My experience is, that the best learning effect is taken by noobs, when their questions were put [on hold].

Comment: for first one if i try 1523 it give me 14797487059.353 which is the right one

Comment: A float isn't large enough to do the calculation, the numbers overflowed.  If you use a double they both output the same number.

Comment: @ibrahiem I have voted to reopen your question *but it still was not good enough*. You should put all your information in the question. "The output is different" can hardly be called 'information'. I have edited your comment answers into the text, next time please do that yourself - do not only answer in comments.

Comment: @ibrahiemMohamed Here's an example of the largest continuous floating point value: http://code.hackerearth.com/fa41b9P I'm not an expert on floating point math, so I don't have much to say on this.  But even though float has a large max, it becomes less precise the larger the number is.   At my link it shows you the largest whole number I could get before I couldn't add 1.0 anymore.  Notice how much smaller it is from the values your program is spitting out.  Beyond that whole number range the answer is imprecise and thus incorrect.

Comment: I could not replicate this issue. If anything, the second one should work better than the first, because r is promoted to a double before multiplication is done. In the first one, it is only promoted to a float.

Comment: I case anyone is wondering, This shows OPs second example working as it should, no negative output: http://ideone.com/WTW944 . The number is pretty far from a float overflow anyways.

Comment: @RedAlert Except that number is incorrect. If you used long doubles (or just a double) you'd get 14797486501.627, not 14797487059.353f.  I've updated my example at the link above on hackerearth to show that.

Comment: @leetNightshade The number isn't necessarily incorrect. It is perhaps not as precise as you want it to be, but that is unrelated to the problem the OP is having. In fact, the second output IS a double, so your statement is contradictory.

Comment: @leetNightshade Looking at your link, I think you are confusing yourself by using a more precise version of pi (thus getting a different output in your last two prints). Change the defintion of `dPi` to `const double dPi=pi;` and you will get a clearer picture of what's going on. I've made a couple changes to your code to show you what type `r` is promoted to before being multiplied: http://ideone.com/IVfnEY

Comment: @leetNightshade Perhaps you missed the edit in the OP, which states "If I input 1523 the first one gives me 14797487059.353, which is the right answer, but the second one gives a negative number." Clearly, a mere precision issue is not the problem here.

Comment: @RedAlert OP didn't post that, someone who edited it did.  The issue is precision, it has to do with the order things are upcast.  I updated my link showing how the order and the type of variable affects the result.

Comment: I updated my link showing how the order and the type of variable affects the result.  Results can be different across compilers, so I might have different results from OP. The output at the link matches VS2013 w/ Update 4.

Comment: @RedAlert "The number isn't necessarily incorrect. It is perhaps not as precise as you want it to be."  Spot on. If I run this in Python which doesn't have overflow like C/C++, I get 14797499000.540071 and 14797499000.54007.  If you plug the calculations into google or wolfram alpha they show similar results to Python, and how imprecise it is above.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your screenshot is not what you've posted here. I'd advise that in the future, if you want help with a problem you're having, you post the code you're having problems with - not code that's completely different.

In this case, the problem is simple - `r*r*r` is too big to fit inside of one int. You can change `r` to be type `long long` and this issue should go away. Alternatively, you can use either of the two blocks of code you've posted here, as they both work as you expect.